# Stroke a path so that it's rendered half in one color and half in another

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-decorations

This is a question that's been asked twice before, but both of the previous solutions involve clipping; my paths are more complicated and I have a lot of them, the clipping solutions provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233922/two-parallel-curved-edges-in-tikz-or-one-curved-edge-with-two-colors-side-by-s) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258806/how-to-draw-two-lines-side-by-side-with-tikz) don't work for me because they rely on pre-computing an offset to define a clip path encompassing "one side" of the path.

Here's my current MWE, I use the curveto decoration and the raise option to shift the curve to one side of the path or the other. It almost works, and I'd like to know how to address these two problems

1. Artifacts at the endpoints (seen in the render). How do I get rid of those?
2. The code is really untikz, I'd like to replace the macro \sidebyside with something that looks like a tikz command.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

    \tikzset{
        draw left/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                curveto,
                raise={.5*\the\pgflinewidth}
            }
        },
        draw right/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
            curveto,
            raise={-.5*\the\pgflinewidth}}
        }
    }
    \newcommand{\sidebyside}[3]{%
        \draw [draw left, #1] #3;%
        \draw [draw right, #2] #3;%
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, line width=6pt]
    \useasboundingbox (-.3,-.3) rectangle (1.3, .3);[!
    % In practice this path is going to be determined 
    % by node positions and bending commands that makes        
    % using it as one side of a clip region (as in the 
    % previous solutions to this problem) challenging.

    % Not repeating the path computation and having a 
    % more tikz syntax than this macro would a bonus
    \sidebyside{densely dotted, red}{blue}{(0,0) -- (1,0)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263059/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for your question to make this more Ti*k*Zy: this can be achieve with the `show path construction` decoration.

**UPDATE**: I tried to understand where the "feature" comes from and believe to have understood things well enough to remove it. It comes from the `\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}` in `\pgfdeclaredecoration{curveto}{initial}{...}`. Why is that? All points on the curve are raised. When connecting to the last point, Ti*k*Z thus sees a slope, and correspondingly tilts the straight segment. The really clean and "once and for all" fix would be to convince Ti*k*Z that there is no slope, something that requires major surgery and is likely to break something that worked before. You may, though, make a feature request at [the pgf GitHub site](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf). For the time being, I propose the following "minimal invasive" fix:

1. Declare a "new" `curveto` decoration `cappedcurveto` that does not draw the last stretch.
2. Shorten the ends of the paths by the corresponding negative amount.

This works, at least in the examples. The `show path construction` decoration is used to make things more Ti*k*Zy, all you need to do is to say

```
\draw[left side/.style={densely dotted, orange},side by side](0,-0.3) to[bend right] (1,-0.3);
```

Full example

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}
\makeatletter
% This is the original curveto decoration:
% 
% \pgfdeclaredecoration{curveto}{initial}{%
%   \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100]
%   {
%     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
%   }%
%   \state{final}{\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}}%
% }%
% the "feature" comes from the \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
% which adds a line from the last *raised* point on the curve to 
% to the last point of the path.
% To "repair" it we drop the last lines
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cappedcurveto}{initial}{%
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }%
  \state{final}{%\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }%
}%
\makeatother

    \tikzset{
        draw left/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                cappedcurveto,
                raise={.5*\pgflinewidth}
            }
        },
        draw right/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
            cappedcurveto,
            raise={-.5*\pgflinewidth}}
        },
        side by side/.style={decoration={show path construction,
         curveto code={
          \draw[draw left,left side]
           (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);
          \draw[draw right,right side]
          (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);},
        lineto code={
          \draw[draw left,left side]
           (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
          \draw[draw right,right side]
          (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);}
        },decorate}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, line width=6pt,shorten >=-\pgflinewidth/2,right side/.style={blue}]
    \draw[left side/.style={densely dotted, red},side by side](0,0) to (1,0);
    \draw[left side/.style={densely dotted, orange},side by side](0,-0.3) to[bend right] (1,-0.3);
    \draw[left side/.style={densely dotted, yellow},side by side](0,0.3) to[bend left] (1,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<s>As you can see, the "feature" is still there. A way to remove it would be to use a full-fledged decoration automaton.</s> The "feature" is gone. ;-)

I'd also like to advertise something that works also for more complicated paths, and uses `decorations.markings` to raise and lower the path. It is largely taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496870), where you can find more applications thereof.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcounter{parrow}
\tikzset{record path/.style={/utils/exec=\tikzset{parrow/.cd,#1},
  decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0 with
    {\setcounter{parrow}{1}%\typeout{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
    \path (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/dist}/2) coordinate (parrowt-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow})
   (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/dist}/2)coordinate (parrowb-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow});
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mystep}{(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-4pt)/int(1+(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-4pt)/2pt)}
     \xdef\mystep{\mystep}},
  mark=between positions 2pt and 1 step \mystep pt with {\stepcounter{parrow}%
   \path (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/dist}/2) coordinate (parrowt-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow})
   (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/dist}/2)coordinate (parrowb-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow});}
    }},reconstruct top/.style={insert path={plot[variable=\t,samples at={1,...,\number\value{parrow}},smooth] (parrowt-#1-\t)}},
  reconstruct bottom/.style={insert path={plot[variable=\t,samples at={\number\value{parrow},\the\numexpr\value{parrow}-1,...,1},smooth]
  (parrowb-#1-\t)}},
  parrow/.cd,dist/.initial=6pt,step/.initial=2pt,name/.initial={}}
\tikzset{back and forth/.style={decoration={show path construction,
    moveto code={},
    lineto code={
      \path[record path={name=tmp}] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      \draw[back,reconstruct top=tmp,shorten >=-0.67pt,shorten <=-0.67pt];
      \draw[forth,reconstruct bottom=tmp,shorten >=-0.67pt,shorten <=-0.67pt];
    },
    curveto code={
      \path[record path={name=tmp}] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      \draw[back,reconstruct top=tmp,shorten >=-0.67pt,shorten <=-0.67pt];
      \draw[forth,reconstruct bottom=tmp,shorten >=-0.67pt,shorten <=-0.67pt];
    },
    closepath code={
      \path[record path={name=tmp}] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      \draw[back,reconstruct top=tmp,shorten >=-0.67pt,shorten <=-0.67pt];
      \draw[forth,reconstruct bottom=tmp,shorten >=-0.67pt,shorten <=-0.67pt];} },decorate},back/.style={densely
dotted,red},forth/.style={blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, line width=6pt,parrow/dist=6pt]
    \path[back and forth] (0,0) to[out=0,in=0] (1,-1) to[out=180,in=180]
    (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This raises the question whether or not one can combine these things to provide us with one smooth continuous path. The answer is yes. This variant comes with two options. Option 1 is clumsy and safe(r). Option 2 is less clumsy but can backfire. It is (almost) as bad as using `\pgfextra` for a path. So if you use it, be warned. (A technical aside: the more recent versions of Ti*k*Z come with a `use path` key. However, this is not the `use path` variant introduced in [Qrrbrbirlbel's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045). For the following to work, we need Qrrbrbirlbel's variant, which is called `reuse path`. The now official `use path` won't do the job. If you want to know why, make a major donation to the [marmot recovery foundation](https://marmots.org/). ;-))

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cappedcurveto}{initial}{%
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }%
  \state{final}{%\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }%
}%
\tikzset{reuse path/.code={%
    \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}}
}% unfortunately this is *not* the definition of the `use path` key that has
% been added to the pgfmanual!
\makeatother

    \tikzset{
        draw left/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                cappedcurveto,
                raise={.5*\pgflinewidth}
            }
        },
        draw right/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
            cappedcurveto,
            raise={-.5*\pgflinewidth}}
        },
        unsafe side by side/.style={save path=\pathA,
        /utils/exec={\draw[right side,draw right,reuse path=\pathA];
    \draw[left side,draw left,reuse path=\pathA];}}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, line width=6pt,shorten >=-\pgflinewidth/2,right
side/.style={blue},left side/.style={densely dotted, red}]
    \path[save path=\pathA]  (0,0) to[out=0,in=0] (1,-1) to[out=180,in=180]
    (2,0);
    \draw[right side,draw right,reuse path=\pathA];
    \draw[left side,draw left,reuse path=\pathA];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, line width=6pt,shorten >=-\pgflinewidth/2,right
side/.style={blue},left side/.style={densely dotted, red}]
    \path[unsafe side by side]   (0,0) to[out=0,in=0] (1,-1) to[out=180,in=180]
    (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This finally allows us to address [Ulrike Fischer's request](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508237/stroke-a-path-so-that-its-rendered-half-in-one-color-and-half-in-another/508254?noredirect=1#comment1285393_508254).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cappedcurveto}{initial}{%
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }%
  \state{final}{%\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }%
}%
\tikzset{reuse path/.code={%
    \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}}
}% unfortunately this is *not* the definition of the `use path` key that has
% been added to the pgfmanual!
\makeatother
    \tikzset{
        draw left/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                cappedcurveto,
                raise={.5*\pgflinewidth}
            }
        },
        draw right/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
            cappedcurveto,
            raise={-.5*\pgflinewidth}}
        },
        unsafe side by side/.style={save path=\pathA,
        /utils/exec={\draw[right side,draw right,reuse path=\pathA];
    \draw[left side,draw left,reuse path=\pathA];}}
    }
\def\LstTikZlings{"bear","penguin","marmot","owl","koala","coati","snowman","mouse","moles","sloth","pig","cat","hippo","rhino"}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nTikZlings}{dim({\LstTikZlings})}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\nTikZlings}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, line width=6pt,shorten >=-\pgflinewidth/2,right
side/.style={blue},left side/.style={densely dotted, red}]
    \path[save path=\pathA]  (0,0) to[out=0,in=0] (1,-1) to[out=180,in=180]
    (2,0);
    \draw[right side,draw right,reuse path=\pathA];
    \draw[left side,draw left,reuse path=\pathA,save path=\pathL];
    \path[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 3pt and 1 step 7pt with {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myindex}{int(mod(\X+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}-1,\nTikZlings))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytikzling}{{\LstTikZlings}[\myindex]}
    \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}=1
    \expandafter\csname\mytikzling\endcsname[scale=0.11,yshift=-12pt,rotate=-90]
    \else
    \expandafter\csname\mytikzling\endcsname[scale=0.11,yshift=-12pt]
    \fi
    }}},reuse path=\pathL];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and now a small tikzling in every compartment and then let it move ;-)

Comment: There is an open issue along those lines: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/622

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks! But I do not quite understand the purpose of the issue. This can be done with a simple `\clip` or `reverseclip`. Of course it can also be done with the above, I think.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I was trying to do it with a decoration but that resulted in an overshoot at sharp corners: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291072/draw-stroke-inside-outside-of-path-for-arbitrary-shapes-and-nodes

Comment: @HenriMenke The capped decorations do no better in this regard, they are also not designed for this. What is wrong with clipping?

Comment: Thank you! I had an inkling that the issue with the artifacts went all the way down to the definition of `curveto` and not my use of it. I ended up using option 1, thank you! (In my personal opinion this is a "bug" in `curveto` but I'm not familiar enough with the situation to make a convincing case; if it worked the other way perhaps something else would behave unexpectedly.)

Comment: @EdgarA.BeringIV There are many definitions of "bug" on the market, and there are certainly some by which this is one. However, I doubt it is very straightforward to fix, but I may be wrong. We dump many task on the viewer/graphics card and I personally find it hard to keep track of who is doing what. The fact that ordinary thick lines work so well is, AFAIK, not necessarily due to Ti*k*Z's internal processing but because its author knew very well what could be dumped on the graphics card/viewer, and now noobs like me mess around with it...